# Google App Engine - separating web & business applications

Tags: google-app-engine

In our home-made systems, we made a point to separate web applications from backend applications, so that then can be deployed and scaled separately.

```
E.g. we had:
- CustomerServices backend, exposing REST (java ".war" deployed on 3 machines)
- ReportServices backend, exposing REST  (java ".war" deployed on 2 machines)
- Web frontend, exposing HTML/JSP, (java ".war" deployed on 3 machines)
When of course the frontend invoked services from the backends.
```

We'd like to achieve the same in Google App Engine. We looked into "Modules" (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) but they are experimental. 
What is the mainstream, stable way to work?

Thanks

Comment: "The mainstream, stable way to work" is Modules. Google keeps things as beta or experimental for much longer than usual: GAE itself only came out of beta three years after it was in widespread use. And GMail was even longer.

Comment: As for the modules they are still not very stable. I've tried using them not long ago and in my case they weren't the most useful. I had lots of issues getting local environment to behave similarly to production. In the end I had to pretty much not use modules locally and run each module as a separate application and in production I deploy them as a single module.

Comment: So for running a critical app, be aware of that experimental label. It might bite you big time. And you won't be able to get google support even if you pay for it, as it is experimental.

Comment: thanks for this important warning,  markovuksanovic

Answer (score 0):

You can always have three different AppEngine applications. All of them live independently of each other. With AppEngine you don't need to worry about deploying on multiple machines as AppEngine provides scalability "out of the box". Here I assumed that multiple .war files are used to horizontally scale the application.

The only difference is that with the above setup your each one of your AppEngine applications will have it's own datastore. If you need to share the datastore you can use Google Cloud SQL (I know it's not exactly the same as Cloud Datastore but at the moment works much better if you need to have your storage a shared resource amongst the applications) and establish the connection with the same instance from all AppEngine applications.